# how to get list in head tag using puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I want to get meta data in head tag using puppeteer.

but I got a lot of empty objects.

here is my code:

```
const description = await page.$eval("head > meta[name='description']", (e) => e.content);
console.log(description);

const title = await page.$eval('head > title', (e) => e.textContent);
console.log(title);

const headList = await page.$$eval('head', (e) => console.log(e))
console.log(headList) // {}
```

I want to get list like [meta, meta, meta, meta] <- like this.
In chrome browser console, I got a list using

`const a = document.querySelectAll('meta');`

Comment: Could you show a [mcve] of the site and explicitly state the data you're trying to get from it?`await page.$$eval('head', (e) => console.log(e))` doesn't make much sense (returning undefined) unless you've already attached a console listener or are expecting to open up the console to see the output. I'm guessing `$` runs a body query selector, not a head.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for your answer ggolen. I already find a solution in my code.
`const list = await page.evaludate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('meta'), (e) => { return e. content }))` This is worked for me. Thank you again!

Comment: Great. Please post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so others can benefit from your research and the post will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its code is work for me. but I got some issues when the puppeteer launch its browser on docker container environment.

My OS is mac os M1.
So, I am shooting this problem so on.

```
const list = await page.evaludate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('meta'), (e) => { return e. content }))
```